# Does Nodogsplash on Raspberry Pi 3 support PHP?

Tags: php, captiveportal

I am setting up a captive portal using Nodogsplash, on a Raspberry Pi 3. The landing web page is a form with an action that points to a PHP file. While this works elsewhere, with Nodogsplash I get "Error 503".

I am wondering if Nodogsplash supports PHP by default, and if not, is there a way to set it up support PHP.

Thanks

Comment: @N.B. — I spent 30 seconds looking at Nodogsplash before I found https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash/tree/master/forward_authentication_service/nodog

Comment: I am a bit lost with the question... `Nodogsplash` is something that you install *on* raspberry Pi... `PHP` is *also* something that you install *on* raspberry Pi. So how "Does Nodogsplash support PHP" pose a question? Also, whose *landing page* are you referencing?

Comment: Nodogsplash has its own web server, which may or may not support PHP. @N.B. At least one other Google search says it does NOT support PHP. So the presence of PHP files in the Github repo is a good sign, but better if someone has actually creating a Nodogsplash landing page with PHP content (@Rushikumar in a captive portal, users land by default to a single web page, on connecting to the hotspot)

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from the Nodogsplash mailing list:

*NodogSplash does not support php, hence the Error 503.

To do this you will need NodogSplash FAS:
http://nodogsplash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html
https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash/tree/master/forward_authentication_service
There is a very simple test server still up at the time of writing making it easy to test and get to grips with FAS.
It is quite simple once you have figured out the principle. Give it a try. You will need to modify your code to return at least $tok back to the url in $authaction.*